# Sites not visible under the Sites node in Connection Pane

Tags: asp.net, iis, server, webserver

I am setting up a new Site in IIS on a Web Server, and for some reason, I am unable to see the sites I create under the Sites node in the **Connections Pane** on the left. I have attached screenshots of IIS in the Web Server, which has the issue, and that of an App Server where the Site is visible in the connections pane.

What might cause this weird issue?

[image: Error]

[image: Normal Behavior]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost 2 days on this issue, I was able to figure out what caused this issue. The `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config` on the Web Server contains different configuration files that define the settings and behavior of the IIS Web Server. This folder contains a XML configuration file named `applicationHost.config`, which is the main configuration file for IIS and contains the global settings that apply to the entire web server.

In my case, this file got corrupted while I was executing some PowerShell scripts to set up App Pool and Site in IIS. The `<sites>` element, which was supposed to be added as a child of the `<system.applicationHost>` element, and as a sibling to `<applicationPools>`, `<log>`, `<webLimits>`, etc., was added in an additional `<system.applicationHost>` node which was created by the script.

*Corrupt applicationHost.config file:*
[image: Corrupt applicationHost.config file]

I fixed the issue by moving the `<sites>` node to the correct `<system.applicationHost>` element and removing the extra `<system.applicationHost>` from the `applicationHost.config` file.

*applicationHost.config file after applying the fix:*
[image: applicationHost.config file after applying the fix]

Special mention to this article by Michael Noto in IIS Support blog which helped me fix the issue: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/the-iis-management-console-connection-pane-doesn-t-show-any/ba-p/1167145

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I suppose the first simple question is are you adding the sites to IIS, or expecting some sites you copied the folders to the server to appear?

Even if the site been copied to that server, you still have to right click on the sites, and choose add-site.

E.g., this:

[image]

So, it is not clear if you are adding the sites, and then the next time you launch IIS, then you don't see the sites?

Or is the issue that you are copying the folder(s) in question to say wwwroot and then in a sub folder the site?

So, even after a copy of say a web site that is inside of a folder?

You will have to right click in IIS, and choose "Add Site" as above shows.

If the adding of a site does not "hold" or "stick" after having done so?

I would try launching IIS manager as an administrator.

E.g., like this:

[image]

Comment: To add context, I was implementing the CI/CD release pipeline for an application on Azure DevOps. I used a PowerShell scripts to create App Pool, Site, copy the published web app files to the server, and then to do some additional configuration on IIS. I believe one of the IIS configuration files somehow got corrupted while I was doing so, and I was able to figure it out fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the connections pane doesn't refresh automatically. Try right-clicking the Sites node in the connections pane and selecting Refresh, this action should update the display of all newly created sites. Also, try restarting the IIS service on the web server, this might help.

[image]